# memory leak trace

Tags: c++, new-operator

I have overridden my operator new[] as

```
void* operator new[](std::size_t sz, const char *file, int line)

{
    void* mem = malloc(sz);

    if(mem == 0){
            printf("Could not allocate the desired memory, the new operator fails\n");
            std::abort();
        }
    printf("Allocation has been done!\n");
    printf("Allocation has been done! In %s, line #%i, %p[%i]\n", file, line, mem, sz);
    return mem;

}
#define DEBUG_NEW2 new[](__FILE__, __LINE__)
#define new[] DEBUG_NEW2
```

My program mainly uses this type of new operator that's why I'm more concerned about it.
However, compiler gives me "missing whitespace after the macro name [-Werror]" error message. I tried to play around with "#define new[] DEBUG_NEW2". In some cases it compiles OK, but I don't get overridden new[] then.

Comment: There is no such thing as operator new in C... or namespaces... this is C++

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is the line which begins with `#define new[]`

You are trying to create a macro with the name `new[]`.

Firstly, this is illegal because a macro name has to be a valid identifier, which means it contains only letters, underscore, digits and may not begin with a digit.

Secondly, you are trying to give a new meaning to a keyword. This is not allowed and means your program is invalid or gives undefined behavior.

There is no need to add such a macro in order to overload the operator new[]. In fact, all you need to do is declare a function with the signature `void* operator new[](size_t)` in the wanted scope, and it will be called automatically for array allocations.

Comment: Well, how do I replace default new with the one that I declared. For example, if my program uses something like "int *m = new int[99];"
I want my program to print out a message saying which line the allocation was called.

Comment: @Bdar just add an void* operator new[](size_t)  in the desired scope and it will automatically be used when allocating arrays.